# Is there a way to access environment variables in an LLVM pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I was wondering if there was a way to access environment variables while writing an LLVM pass. In my source file, I read a certain environment variable, depending on whose value the execution is furthered. I ought to recreate that in my pass and add a few checks therein.

I would really appreciate if there was some tutorial laying out these details in form of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just use [cstdlib's `getenv` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/) in your pass, just like in any other C++ code.